# Git hangs indefinitely when trying to push --all to GitHub

Tags: git, github

When I try and push `--all` to GitHub, the Git transfer starts out fast, slows down, and eventually stops. It doesn't  fail, it just slows to a halt. What's going on? This is really frustrating, I'd like to get my code pushed, but every time I try this, it slows to a stop. I've tried on multiple networks, so I don't think it's my network connection.

Comment: What's the output of `git config -l`?

Comment: I was able to force it through by just trying over and over again; when I ran it with `-v` (verbose mode) it worked better for some reason and was able to complete.

Comment: Are you using https? For large repositories, https might be slow.
You can try using the ssh address instead.

Comment: What git protocol is/was being used here?

Comment: check your ssh key is the one which set in your github repo check your vpn (turn it off)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and realized it was because I had set a default port number (and username) in my `~/.ssh/config`. I had recently decided to use it for custom ssh ports and my normal user name on webservers I access. Remember, star means ALL ssh connections! >_<

```
# This is bad!
Host *
  Port 4876
  User myuser
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following the guide here on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4. 
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

What worked for me was removing the config they ask you to add.
So **DO NOT** add this config file

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```